# MYSQL strict mode, how to use it?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've come to know about this strict mode while on my course, i was advised to turn it off i and for the moment i did. But if strict mode is there, it surely has a reason for it.
First let me show the code that got the error

```
SELECT `first_name`,
       `last_name`, 
       `order_date`, 
       `amount` 
 FROM `customers`
    JOIN `orders`
        ON `customers`.`id` = `orders`.`customer_id`
GROUP BY `orders`.`customer_id`;
```

and i got ERROR CODE 1055

[image: error image]

for what i was told, i had to use all my fields in the GROUP BY unless aggregated.

So it should be like this.

```
SELECT `first_name`,
       `last_name`, 
       `order_date`, 
       `amount` 
 FROM `customers`
    JOIN `orders`
        ON `customers`.`id` = `orders`.`customer_id`
GROUP BY `orders`.`customer_id`,`order_date`, 'amount';
```

The code would "work" but it would group by `order_date` and 'amount', with i didn't want to happen.

for the `amount` i had to use a SUM(), so i didn't had to use it anymore on GROUP BY, but `order_date` is still there.

[image]

Since `amount is still here` it would show all the date options, i do know that it is possible to have only one date per id=id

for future reference, how should i use in good ways the STRICT MODE, or should i turn it off?

Comment: I can't even answer, because I don't know what you are actually trying to do in your query.  The actual mode you are referring to is `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, and it means that the query must follow the ANSI standard when using `GROUP BY`.  This, in turn, means that if you `GROUP BY` one or more columns, then you may only select those columns _or_ other columns appearing in _aggregate_ functions (e.g. `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.).  Add some sample data and output to your question and maybe someone can answer.

Comment: You can read about how to change strict mode and other SQL modes here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: You used quotes for grouping  `amount` instead of backticks. That can't work. Using quotes, it turns from column name into a simple string.

Comment: My question wasn't properly made, I should re-write it or delete it, the code was a test and so it is the database he is in, My question should have been how to properly make a group by, having in mind the strict mode, as for my code, I wanted him to show data based on customer.id = order.customer_id and then return to me only one column per customer, as said above the `order_date` by itself isn't a good idea since it returns a random. I should use a MIN or MAX to it, but it did clarify a lot for me, I need to know exactly what I want my data to show. Thank for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generally strict mode is preferred in MySQL as it helps you avoid some common mistakes such as this one.
2. When you select columns that are not included in your `GROUP BY` clause without any aggregations, MySQL *without strict mode* may return any random row, and you cannot make any assumptions about which row would be returned.  MySQL *in strict mode*, as many other RDBMS, raises an error so that you are forced to fix your query.
3. To write your query correctly, you first need to figure out what data do you want to get for `order_date` and `amount` -- e.g. should it be the newest order made by customer or something else.

Comment: Thank you, over the night it did came to me the fact that order_date didn't made sense to be there, for such I assume I should use a MIN to get the oldest order date, or MAX for the latest one, but thanks a lot for the clarification!